# Android Studio can install app on one physical device but not another of the same model

Tags: android-studio, usb, adb, androidphone

I successfully can install an app (for debugging) on one phone. When I try to install the same app on another phone that is the same model as the first phone, the installation fails.

The idea logs for both installs are identical up until “get process ids.” The failed install log includes:

```
Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: package not debuggable: com.mccoystoys.canview
```

**Successful install:**

> ```
> …
> TRC_BEG [17280][17280] : Installer request:dump 
> TRC_BEG [17280][17280] : Command Dump 
> TRC_BEG [17280][17280] : get process ids 
> TRC_BEG [17280][17280] : CmdCommand::GetApksFromPath 
> TRC_BEG [17280][17280] : processing APK 
>  …
> ```

**Failed install:**

> ```
> …
> TRC_BEG [25983][25983] : Installer request:dump 
> TRC_BEG [25983][25983] : Command Dump 
> TRC_BEG [25983][25983] : get process ids 
> LOG_ERR [25983][25983] : Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: package not debuggable: com.mccoystoys.canview
> TRC_BEG [25983][25983] : CmdCommand::GetApksFromPath 
> TRC_BEG [25983][25983] : processing APK
> …
> ```

Why would the app be “not debuggable” for one device but not the other device?

Comment: Have you checked the "Allow USB debugging" setting in the developer settings?

Comment: Is it possible that an app of the same packageName is already installed on the second device? If that app was signed using a different key, then your app can not be installed unless you uninstall the existing app.